# Web server access

Tags: glassfish-3

This probably is an elementary question in networking but I am stuck due to it.
I have a rest web service I have deployed on a machine with windows xp. I can access it using localhost:8080 uri from the same machine. But now I want to use it from the other machines in my LAN. If I ping to my chine from other machines I can access it. I can see the ipaddress:8080 url of my machine from other machines. In my client which is deployed on the other machines glassfish, I am trying to access my web service with the ip address or the computer name in the url but i cannot see any communication between both machines( I am watching the server.log of the webservice machine). Please tell me how do I configure the single glassfish to cater to all machines in the lan.
Any help/ suggestion is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Do you get a specific error message about the problem?

You need to do some networking diagnostics.  Try telnet or putty to see if the port is reachable from one machine to the other.  Basically if you can connect without an error, it's good.  Putty will just close right away, but it will at least prove the port is reachable.  You might have a firewall blocking it or some other networking trouble.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with javascript.

Since no specific error is generated for javascript errors, i commented all code and then removed comment one line at a time to find the syntax error.

When the error was resolved in javascript it went till the ajax call. Untill then nothing as the entire javascript function comes under undefined!!

Wonder how to trap such coding errors in javascript. I can use firebug for debuging only on the server machine.

Thanks